# Python Countdown while other code running

Tags: python

I want it so that the player only has a 500-600 milisecond frame to type 1 or 2. I don't know how to do this and the only timers I found only do

```
time.sleep(1)
```

Here is my code:

```
        game = 1
    while game == 1:
        play = input(print("'display picture in other window' [1] for right [2] for wrong "))
        if '1' in play:
            print("You shot the Criminal! + 1 point")
            point = point + 1
            row = row + 1
            if row == 3:
                unlock2 = 1
                print ("You gained 2 bonus points!")
                point = point + 2
                row = 0
            if unlock2 == 1:
                point = point + (point/2)
                print ("You gained bonus points!")

        elif '2' in play:
            print("You shot an innocent! Game Over!")
            break

            game = 0
```

EDIT: redacted edit

Comment: The easiest way to do something like that would be to measure the time the user takes (using `time.time()`)

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I added one as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want would be to measure the time the user takes for a response, like this:

```
import time

def respond_in_time(msg, s):
    start = time.time()
    response = input(msg)
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
    if end - start > s:
        return False
    else:
        return response
```

Usage:

```
>>> respond_in_time("What is 2+2? ", 0.5) # User responds in time
'4'
>>> respond_in_time("What is 2+2? ", 0.5) # User is too slow
False
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm new to these functions with variable... variables? How do they work??

Comment: @CatsInSpace I could give you an answer, but it is probably easier if you just pick up a good Python course, for example [this](http://www.learnpython.org).